# Record: restrict to existing keys with typed entries

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
export const myRecord = {
  Entry1: {
    title: 'hey ho',
    data: {
      version: 1,
      valid: true
    }
  },
  Entry2: {
    title: 'hey hey',
    data: {
      version: 2,
      valid: false
    }
  }
} as const;

export type MyRecordsIds = keyof typeof myRecord;

export function doSomething(recordId: MyRecordsIds){
  //does something
}
```

This structure allows me to add new entries to `myRecord` without adding them to `MyRecordIds` explicitly.
`MyRecordsIds` type, in turn, allows me to restrict these IDs all over the code.

So far so good. But now I'd like to restrict the values in `myRecord` to a certain type, like this one:

```js
export interface Entry {
  title: string;
  data: {
    version: number;
    valid: boolean;
  }
}
```

The most obvious solution is this:

```js
export const myRecord: Record<string, Entry> = {
  Entry1: {
    title: 'hey ho',
    data: {
      version: 1,
      valid: true
    }
  },
  Entry2: {
    title: 'hey hey',
    data: {
      version: 2,
      valid: false
    }
  }
};
```

The restriction works, but I loose the restriction on `MyRecordsIds` type (it becomes `string`, because of `Record<string,Entry>`).

The closest I got so far is this:

```js
const myRecord = {
  Entry1: {
    title: 'hey ho',
    data: {
      version: 1,
      valid: true
    }
  },
  Entry2: {
    title: 'hey hey',
    data: {
      version: 2,
      valid: false
    }
  }
} as const;

type MyRecordsIds = keyof typeof myRecord;

export const myRecordTyped: Record<MyRecordsIds, Entry> = myRecord;
```

This restricts both record entries and ids, meaning that the build fails if:

1. I'm trying to use `doSomething` with some string that is not a key in the record.
2. I'm trying to add entry which doesn't comply to the `Entry` type.

This approach, however, has a severe disadvantage. If one of the entries is wrong the build will fail on the assignment (instead of pointing to the problematic line in the record), which makes it hard to track down the problem:

```js
export const myRecordTyped: Record<MyRecordsIds, Entry> = myRecord; // The build fails here because the types are not compliant
```

Is there a better way to achieve this behavior while keeping restriction on both record entries types and record ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you just want a helper function to let you define `myRecord` in such a way that it accepts any keys but restricts values to `Entry`:

```
const asMyRecord = <T extends Record<keyof T, Entry>>(t: T): Record<keyof T, Entry> => t;
```

You'd use it like this:

```
export const myRecord = asMyRecord({
    Entry1: {
        title: 'hey ho',
        data: {
            version: 1,
            valid: true
        }
    },
    Entry2: {
        title: 'hey hey',
        data: {
            version: 2,
            valid: false
        }
    }
});
```

If you try to set any property values to something that isn't assignable to `Entry`, you'll get an error:

```
const badMyRecord = asMyRecord({
    EntryNope: {
        title: 123, // error! number is not strng
        data: {
            version: "one", // error! string is not number
            valid: false
        }
    }
})
```

And `MyRecord` is known to have the specific literal keys as before:

```
type MyRecordsIds = keyof typeof myRecord; // "Entry1" | "Entry2"
```

So it should stay reasonably strongly typed (the current `asMyRecord` ends up producing a value of type `Record<keyof T, Entry>`):

```
myRecord.Entry2.title = "okay"; // okay
myRecord.Entry2.oops = false; // error! "oops" doesn't exist on Entry
myRecord.Entry3.title = "nope";  // error! "Entry3" not "Entry1" | "Entry2"
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLigT2QbwFDKHJjBgA2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3AUQCZxhzX5H-IAbtBrAA9iGogArgFsARtFYCiguGWDtq8sWIpwQyogF88phBLrI4NALKYAShAtR2yALzIAPABVkEAA9IEHYaZCcXdi8AawhMMRhkHwAaNAxMAD4MgAowah8ASmoIsVcYuISk1PR6TI8M4lY8PAsQK1lHZ1K3Txt7EtdsviIarABGXjYVEnIqZAByAAs45EWxeeSpgU5uSZUVYShRCWoxzf2BNQ0tYihpCC3+Y3OTF8JRzAAmPf2ZimolitlpgNo8OFweLgwQcROJJMhPm8LkJ1JpqPAyDQHhdTE8zAUmq0rPI4Ox+l1XB5rHZOpEhlsPgA5MQABzmw2mpH+yDGnwAzKkAPSC-xQKClACEyBkCmgyGAYRAYjAtHoIEY0OQO0hHORh2O8IARBIIIahSLoOKoFK6Ax1fLFcrpXJFFBNfwrmjkBisZrcSZ8c0wJg2chyZEaABJUJU2LxRLBtmVDoDdjMZDC5CGj5jQ3IAA+WY+n0NzRTFPYADpi5W-ihPMbonBMIb05mxE3MHhy5Fq+lPpXdCywp4fRA2xaxZKs0OaHn2GIIDQQPMVYEFSqJGlat3ad0+7U+bWufWs0q2a3CJnLdPs+k+XmlSq77VcwWi-3S81mkA)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! Very elegant solution.

Comment: The return type though seems redundant, it is inferred automatically.

Comment: It is inferred as something narrower than `{Entry1: Entry, Entry2: Entry}`; if that narrower type meets your use case, great.   I was just trying to get `myRecord` to be the same type as `myRecordTyped`.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get is by assigning each of the entries to typed constants

```typescript
export interface Entry {
  title: string
  data: {
    version: number
    valid: boolean
  }
}

const Entry1: Entry = {
  title: 'hey ho',
  data: {
    version: 1,
    valid: true
  }
}

const Entry2: Entry = {
  title: 'hey hey',
  data: {
    version: 2,
    valid: false
  }
}

const myRecord = {
  Entry1,
  Entry2
}

type MyRecordsIds = keyof typeof myRecord

export const myRecordTyped: Record<MyRecordsIds, Entry> = myRecord
```