# How can I keep the original index signature of an object, but still specify the type of its values?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a large object with string keys and typed values. I want to type this object.

```
interface Animal {
    legs: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
}

const Animals: Record<string, Animal> = {
    snake: { legs: 0 },
    dog: { legs: 4 },
    bird: { legs: 2},
    // many more entries...
};
```

If I type the object as Record<string, Animal>, then all strings become valid keys. So there is no protection against me accidentally writing `Animals.birb`. It would be silly to do something like `Record<"snake" | "dog" | "bird" ... , Animal>` because the object is big and has many keys.

If I do not explicitly write a type definition, then TypeScript will infer the type as
`{ snake: { legs: number}, dog: { legs: number}, ... }`.

This is bad because I need TypeScript to know that the type of value is `Animal` and not just `{ legs: number }`,

i.e., the type should be `{ snake: Animal, dog: Animal, ... }`

Writing `as Animal` for every line would be silly.

Is there a better way to type this object?

Comment: Typically you'd do this using a helper function which essentially returns `Record<keyof AnimalsLiteral, Animal>`. See e.g. [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017993/record-restrict-to-existing-keys-with-typed-entries)

Comment: "I need TypeScript to know that the type of value is `Animal` and not just `{ legs: number }`".  Can you articulate why?  Those are the same type; since TS's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), types with the same structure are the same type.  If there's some concrete problem that arises with the type `{legs: number}` other than `Animal`, could you demonstrate with a [mre] that shows it?

Comment: @jcalz Lets say it was `Animal { legs: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  }` and I have a function which only accepts Animals. If I write an object literal like so: `const Animals = { dog: { legs: 4 } }` then the type of Animals.dog.legs is inferred as `number`, which is incompatible with type `0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4`.

Comment: The solution to that would be to use the `satisfies` operator to give the inference you care about without widening, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaEV2N).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Note that you should probably [edit] the example in your question to be closer to your example in the comments so that there is a difference between `Animal` and `{legs: number}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that a variable is assignable to a type without [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) it as that type and potentially throwing away information (like the particular keys), you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const Animals = {
    snake: { legs: 0 },
    dog: { legs: 4 },
    bird: { legs: 2 },
} satisfies Record<string, Animal>;

/* const Animals: {
    snake: {
        legs: 0;
    };
    dog: {
        legs: 4;
    };
    bird: {
        legs: 2;
    };
} */
```

You can see that `Animals` has been inferred with known keys, and with properties whose `legs` are of appropriately narrow [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) instead of the wider `number` type which would have been inferred otherwise.

This also will catch mistakes in your initializer similarly to an annotation:

```
const badAnimals = {
    snake: { legs: 0 },
    dog: { legs: 4 },
    bird: { legs: 2 },
    octopus: { legs: 8 } // error!
} satisfies Record<string, Animal>;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=23&pln=7&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkcIBzAZwC5kAGZAH2QEZnkAmDgZg4BZCAX0KEEAexBUwaDNhxVkAXgLFSVEHADWEOvjKVaDZEIA0akgBNxFPQep1+J86WQAjYFEt3yDrs+FkKjgwYCoYYAhFACUICS8AHmkoUApTWSxcAD4AblEAegAqZAkpGXRMhT0LIM0datdXXyN6PNchNtJrW1VG0mbHTpIOmo8vBr77I04hkzyhZEL80VLpdzhLCvlFFSJXDW1dAim6RjMa7p9DRwDXMe9jgf9z13EEMHEABwBXI30ngAcJmQ+XyyGgUHEUAAhIFgqFwpEYnEoZYkmAUiA0hl5LlREA)

Comment: I ran into an issue when implementing this solution. If I use the satisfies operator, then the type is narrowed down too much: `const Animals: { snake: { legs: 0; }; dog: { legs: 4; }; bird: { legs: 2; } }`. This causes problems later on:

`let arr = [Animals.snake]; // Type inferred: { legs: 0 }[];

arr.push(Animals.dog); // Error, because { legs: 4 } is incompatible with { legs: 0 }.`

I would like the type of `Animals.snake` to still be `{ legs: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 }` or even better, `Animal`

Comment: [See example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkcIBzAZwC5kAGZAH2QEZnkAmDgZg4BZCAX0KEEAexBUwaDNhxVkAXgLFSVEHADWEOvjKVaDZEIA0akgBNxFPQep1+J86WQAjYFEt3yDrs+FkKjgwYCoYYAhFACUICS8AHmkoUApTWSxcAD4AblFyGTgoKGVkAG10TIUAOg1tCABdHOQAehaDQuKfQzp6ZqEyhsIiqGqABwBXKgALAApK+Spqjy8ASma25ABRYvEoAEJkABUATzGUAHJ9XyNOfovkMOQQcUKqKmAKTTdyZDBxZBjIpwTAQSAlcQwP5nS7XHoMfqEIA)

Comment: I'd say that `arr` is an array of snakes, not `Animal`s, and if you want that I'd be explicit and say `let arr: Animal[] = [Animals.snake]`.  But if that's important you could use a helper function instead of `satisfies`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N55J5N). ...

Comment: ... Anyway given the examples in your question this is a followup question and technically out of scope (unless you want to edit your question to mention this use case, but that's why I was asking you for examples that demonstrate a need for `Animal`, in the hopes that I wouldn't spend time writing an answer that didn't actually solve your issue).  If you have further followups you might want to post a new question.